# Android Can't get Stripe charge id after confirming PaymentIntent [3DS2]

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

I'm implementing the `new version of Stripe (SCA-READY), version 12.8.2.`
Everything is working as well.
But I need to get the `charge ID` after confirming the `PaymentIntent`.
`ID` that I receive from my `server` (which forward `stripe response`) after confirming the `PaymentIntent`.
However, I do not receive this `ID` when the process needs 3ds2 (or 3ds).

(the followings snippets only represent the charges part, if you want the full JSON, ask me in comment)

[Here is the response's snippet](https://pastebin.com/pcSfQeqb) without 3ds2 authentification

Then there is the response's snippet when the 3ds2 authentification is needed:

```
"charges": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_1FxfoiHk0bG3YRQo1hU4c6f1"
  },
```

I can't retrieve the charge without the id of this one accord to the stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object)

Then I also don't have any attributs which correspond to the charge in the `PaymentIntent` from `stripe sdk` after the 3ds2 has been processed that I can get in `callback` in the `activityResult` (triggered after the 3ds2 authentification to handle the result):

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == PaymentMethodsActivityStarter.REQUEST_CODE && data != null) {
            val result = PaymentMethodsActivityStarter.Result.fromIntent(data)
            val paymentMethod = result?.paymentMethod
            adapter.renderCard(paymentMethod)
        }
        val isPaymentIntentResult = paymentServiceProvider.stripe.onPaymentResult(
                requestCode, data,
                object : ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {
                    override fun onSuccess(result: PaymentIntentResult) {
                        adapter.processStripeIntent(result.intent)//The intent accessed here hasn't any charges (stuff like amount paymentMethod, but nothing about charges)
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@ClientMainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                })
    }
```

EDIT :
There is a response body with state succeed:

```
{
  "id": "pi_1FxzypHk0bG3YRQop47ZATBv",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "amount": 500,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "client_secret": "secret",
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1578334027,
  "currency": "eur",
  "description": null,
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "next_action": null,
  "payment_method": "pm_1Fv1nxHk0bG3YRQoqldFvopb",
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "receipt_email": null,
  "setup_future_usage": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "status": "succeeded"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No Charge is created until you have finished authenticating the user as part of 3D Secure and te Payment Intent is in either the `succeeded` or `requires_payment_method` state: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents

What does the Payment Intent look like in your Stripe Dashboard at that point?

Comment: even when I have the state succeeded I don't get any charges. I edited my post with a json of it